# Issue with filesize in ForceDownload

Tags: php

The following script is what i'm using to force-download.

```
// grab the requested file's name
$file_name = $_GET['file'];

// make sure it's a file before doing anything!
if(is_file($file_name)) {

    /*
        Do any processing you'd like here:
        1.  Increment a counter
        2.  Do something with the DB
        3.  Check user permissions
        4.  Anything you want!
    */

    // required for IE
    if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression')) { ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off'); }

    // get the file mime type using the file extension
    switch(strtolower(substr(strrchr($file_name, '.'), 1))) {
        case 'pdf': $mime = 'application/pdf'; break;
        case 'zip': $mime = 'application/zip'; break;
        case 'jpeg':
        case 'jpg': $mime = 'image/jpg'; break;
        default: $mime = 'application/force-download';
    }
    header('Pragma: public');   // required
    header('Expires: 0');       // no cache
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate ('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime ($file_name)).' GMT');
    header('Cache-Control: private',false);
    header('Content-Type: '.$mime);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file_name).'"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file_name));    // provide file size
    header('Connection: close');
    readfile($file_name);       // push it out
    exit();

}
```

The issue is above code works properly for files less than **100MB** and it can't works for example for files up than 200MB and saying 177 bytes downloaded.

How i can rid of the issue?

**Edit 1:**

The main script is copied from [here](http://davidwalsh.name/php-force-download).

Thanks!

Comment: There's a line in your php.ini file about the max-upload size. change this to whatever you want. This should fix your problem. `upload_max_filesize = 20M` for example

Comment: In addition to previous comment: make sure your post_max_size is also aligned properly.

Comment: I don't see how the code above is in any way related to uploads?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you are causing PHP to use too much memory by loading the file in to memory in one go - take a look at the contents of downloaded file, and you'll probably see it's plain text and contains a PHP fatal error message.

You would do well to load the file in smaller chunks and pass it back to the webserver to serve, for example, try swapping out your "readfile" line with the following:

```
// Open the file for reading and in binary mode
$handle = fopen($file_name,'rb');
$buffer = '';

// Read 1MB of data at a time, passing it to the output buffer and flushing after each 1MB
while(!feof($handle))
{
  $buffer = fread($handle, 1048576);
  echo $buffer;
  @ob_flush();
  @flush();
}
fclose($handle);
```